# Выполнение задач на cron

Tags: centos, cron, crontab

Добавляю запись в файле `/etc/crontab` к примеру `* * * * * /home/dan/bin/script.sh`
Перезапускаю службу `sudo systemctl restart crond.service`
Но задача не выполняется, в логе никаких ошибок нет.
CentOS 7  VM Bitrix

Comment: crontab -e  и редактирование файла /etc/crontab совершенно разные вещи 

и в /etc/crontab нужно написать не `* * * * * /home/dan/bin/script.sh`

а `* * * * * root /home/dan/bin/script.sh`

имя пользователя нужно указывать от которого запускать данную задачу! можно не root а другого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, перезапускать крон не требуется. Во-вторых, добавлять задачи в крон надо через `сrontab -e`, и в-третьих, чтобы видеть вывод скрипта, надо добавить в начале крон файла строчку mailto=адрес на который будет приходить вывод и, как следствие - ошибки.

А гадать на кофейной гуще можно долго, но малоэффективно.

Comment: Вот что выдает при попытки запустить команду crontab -e
https://s.mail.ru/EEBL/RS9P4qUjj